# Having trouble comparing keys to values given by user input in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, spyder

I'm attempting to build a both-ways morse code translator as a beginner project in Python by using a dictionary to compare each morse code character to its morse sequence. The trouble comes with the *decryption* option in particular, as my current decryption code is built to take in each individual character of each sequence until it reads a space, at which point it's meant to print the letter corresponding to the sequence, then clean out the sequence tracker for everything after the space. In all cases, the decryption instead outputs nothing, skipping straight from taking the input to assuming that decryption has ended and directing back to the menu, without actually outputting any of the letters whose sequences were in the user input.

```
morse_code_dict = {"A":".-", "B":"-...", "C":"-.-.", "D":"-..", "E":".", "F":"..-.",
                   "G":"--.", "H":"....", "I":"..", "J":".---", "K":"-.-", "L":".-..", "M":"--",
                   "N":"-.", "O":"---", "P":".--.", "Q":"--.-", "R":".-.", "S":"...", "T":"-",
                   "U":"..-", "V":"...-", "W":".--", "X":"-..-", "Y":"-.--", "Z":"--..",
                   "1":".----", "2":"..---", "3":"...--", "4":"....-", "5":".....", "6":"-....", 
                   "7":"--...", "8":"---..", "9":"----.", "0":"-----"}





def encrypt(morse_code_dict):

    morse_code_current = ""

    morse_code_current = input("Please enter all of the letters and numbers you want to have encrypted. Enter the letters in uppercase." + '\n')

    for digit in morse_code_current:
        if digit in morse_code_dict.keys():
            print(morse_code_dict[digit])
            print(" ")

    print("Thank you! We'll now be bringing you back to the menu for further translation, or to exit.")
    choice()

    return

def decrypt(morse_code_dict):

    morse_code_current = ""
    morse_code_sequence = ""

    morse_code_current = input("Hello! Please enter each morse code sequence you want turned into a character. Separate each individual sequence with a space." + '\n')

    for digit in morse_code_current:
        if digit == "." or "-":
            morse_code_sequence += digit
        elif digit == " ":
            print(morse_code_dict.keys(morse_code_sequence))
            morse_code_sequence = ""
        else:
            print("One or more of these morse code sequences is inaccurate. Please double-check and try again.")
            decrypt(morse_code_dict)
            morse_code_sequence = ""
    print("Thank you! We'll now be bringing you back to the menu for further translation, or to exit.")
    choice()

    return

def choice():
    input_tracker = ""


    input_tracker = input("Enter your choice now." + '\n')

    if input_tracker == "E":
        encrypt(morse_code_dict)
    elif input_tracker == "D":
        decrypt(morse_code_dict)
    elif input_tracker == "Q":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Please enter a character corresponding to the options shown initially." + '\n')
        choice()

print("Welcome to the both-ways morse code translator!")
print("Please enter 'E' if you want to encrypt a series of characters.")
print("Enter 'D' if you want to decrypt a morse code series.")
print("Enter 'Q' to exit the program.")
choice()
```

Comment: `if digit == "." or digit == "-":` or `if digit in (".", "-"):` or `if digit in ".-":`

Comment: Your current code works like `if (digit == ".") or ("-"):` and `"-"` gives alway `True` so you have `if (digit == ".") or True:` which works like  `if True:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a couple of changes to the loop:

```
 morse_code_dict = {"A":".-", "B":"-...", "C":"-.-.", "D":"-..", "E":".", "F":"..-.",
                   "G":"--.", "H":"....", "I":"..", "J":".---", "K":"-.-", "L":".-..", "M":"--",
                   "N":"-.", "O":"---", "P":".--.", "Q":"--.-", "R":".-.", "S":"...", "T":"-",
                   "U":"..-", "V":"...-", "W":".--", "X":"-..-", "Y":"-.--", "Z":"--..",
                   "1":".----", "2":"..---", "3":"...--", "4":"....-", "5":".....", "6":"-....",
                   "7":"--...", "8":"---..", "9":"----.", "0":"-----"}





def encrypt(morse_code_dict):

    morse_code_current = ""

    morse_code_current = input("Please enter all of the letters and numbers you want to have encrypted. Enter the letters in uppercase." + '\n')

    for digit in morse_code_current:
        if digit in morse_code_dict.keys():
            print(morse_code_dict[digit])
            print(" ")

    print("Thank you! We'll now be bringing you back to the menu for further translation, or to exit.")
    choice()

    return

def decrypt(morse_code_dict):

    morse_code_current = ""
    morse_code_sequence = ""

    morse_code_current = input("Hello! Please enter each morse code sequence you want turned into a character. Separate each individual sequence with a space." + '\n')

    for digit in morse_code_current:
        if digit == "." or digit == "-":  # Need to specify the variable with each 'or' condition
            morse_code_sequence += digit
        elif digit == " ":
            for letter, code in morse_code_dict.items(): # .items() and remove argument
                # Have to loop the dictionary and search.
                if code == morse_code_sequence:
                    print(letter)
                    morse_code_sequence = ""
        else:
            print("One or more of these morse code sequences is inaccurate. Please double-check and try again.")
            decrypt(morse_code_dict)
            morse_code_sequence = ""
    print("Thank you! We'll now be bringing you back to the menu for further translation, or to exit.")
    choice()

    return

def choice():
    input_tracker = ""


    input_tracker = input("Enter your choice now." + '\n')

    if input_tracker == "E":
        encrypt(morse_code_dict)
    elif input_tracker == "D":
        decrypt(morse_code_dict)
    elif input_tracker == "Q":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Please enter a character corresponding to the options shown initially." + '\n')
        choice()

print("Welcome to the both-ways morse code translator!")
print("Please enter 'E' if you want to encrypt a series of characters.")
print("Enter 'D' if you want to decrypt a morse code series.")
print("Enter 'Q' to exit the program.")

choice()
```

Comment: I implemented this change into the code, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I've edited the above code to include everything. But out of interest what Python version are you using?

Comment: 3.7; I'm using Spyder as my development environment. I implemented the entire change you put in, and it still doesn't show anything for the translated letters, still not printing what the translation was supposed to be.

Comment: Hmm... just for consistencies sake, what code are you trying to translate? It might be a problem localized to one or a few letters, rather than a logic problem?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take in input from the user on the command line, where the user enters something like ".- -... -.-.", the program reads that line and copies each character into a string until a space is read, at which point the program outputs the character that corresponds with that sequence. The end result of the sequences I put as example would preferably be
"A
B
C"

Comment: I've tried a various and semi-random amount of characters. I just find it weird because encryption works fine

Comment: I'm not really sure whats going on here... The morse code for 'A B C' works on my machine. Have you tried adding a print statement under the `for digit in morse_code_current:` line? If not, under this line write `print(digit)`. Then we can see if its even getting there in the first place

Comment: I did that, and it did actually print each part of my input; it working on your machine is really great info, though, as it means it's something about my specific case

Comment: It looks like it. I just started a fresh environment and it still runs. So I'm not sure if your Spyder environment has ended up with a conflicting library, or old version of something? Aside from that I don't know if I can help much more.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm trying it in a few different environments now, we'll see what happens